# Perl XSD parsing

Tags: xsd

I have a XSD file that is to be parsed and converted into a XML file.

Is there any way to do it using Perl ??? After xml file is generated, i have to parse that xml file which is the second part, but i was struck in the first part of converting the XSD file to XML format.

XSD is given below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This document was generated by the Objective Systems ASN2XSD Compiler
     (http://www.obj-sys.com).  Version: 6.3.0, Date: 06-May-2010. -->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns="http://www.obj-sys.com/S1AP-PDU-Descriptions"
            targetNamespace="http://www.obj-sys.com/S1AP-PDU-Descriptions"
 xmlns:S1AP-CommonDataTypes="http://www.obj-sys.com/S1AP-CommonDataTypes"
 xmlns:S1AP-PDU-Contents="http://www.obj-sys.com/S1AP-PDU-Contents"
 xmlns:S1AP-Constants="http://www.obj-sys.com/S1AP-Constants"
 xmlns:asn1="http://www.obj-sys.com/v1.0/XMLSchema"
 elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xsd:import namespace="http://www.obj-sys.com/S1AP-CommonDataTypes"
    schemaLocation="S1AP-CommonDataTypes.xsd"/>
   <xsd:import namespace="http://www.obj-sys.com/S1AP-PDU-Contents"
    schemaLocation="S1AP-PDU-Contents.xsd"/>
   <xsd:import namespace="http://www.obj-sys.com/S1AP-Constants"
    schemaLocation="S1AP-Constants.xsd"/>
   <xsd:import namespace="http://www.obj-sys.com/v1.0/XMLSchema"
    schemaLocation="http://www.obj-sys.com/v1.0/XMLSchema/asn1.xsd"/>

   <!-- PDU definition -->
   <xsd:element name="s1AP-PDU" type="S1AP-PDU"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="S1AP-PDU">
      <xsd:choice>
         <xsd:element name="initiatingMessage" type="InitiatingMessage"/>
         <xsd:element name="successfulOutcome" type="SuccessfulOutcome"/>
         <xsd:element name="unsuccessfulOutcome" type="UnsuccessfulOutcome"/>
         <xsd:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
      </xsd:choice>
   </xsd:complexType>

   <xsd:complexType name="InitiatingMessage">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="procedureCode" type="S1AP-CommonDataTypes:ProcedureCode"/>
         <xsd:element name="criticality" type="S1AP-CommonDataTypes:Criticality"/>
         <xsd:element name="value" type="asn1:OpenType"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>

   <xsd:complexType name="SuccessfulOutcome">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="procedureCode" type="S1AP-CommonDataTypes:ProcedureCode"/>
         <xsd:element name="criticality" type="S1AP-CommonDataTypes:Criticality"/>
         <xsd:element name="value" type="asn1:OpenType"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>

   <xsd:complexType name="UnsuccessfulOutcome">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="procedureCode" type="S1AP-CommonDataTypes:ProcedureCode"/>
         <xsd:element name="criticality" type="S1AP-CommonDataTypes:Criticality"/>
         <xsd:element name="value" type="asn1:OpenType"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: there is a tool in java you can try that by googleing

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used one of the free tools from [Objective Systems](http://www.obj-sys.com/free-web-tools.shtml) to convert some [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) data. I believe that you used their tool, ASN2XSD, when you meant to use their ASN2XML tool instead. The XSD tool produces a description document like the one you show in your question that helps another tool format and describe your data, which is not what you wanted.

If you use their ASN2XML tool from the first link above to convert your ASN.1 data, it will produce the XML output you need without losing any data. You can then use Perl's XML tools to parse that data.

Comment: I also wanted to add that IBM has another good ASN.1 to XML conversion tool: http://www.trl.ibm.com/projects/xml/xss4j/docs/axt-readme.html